# Creating custom RubberStamp Annotation Appearance-Stream with PdfSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I have been using **PdfSharp** library in a C# project for saving PDF files with Annotations. I would like to create a **RubberStamp** Annotation with a custom image. PfSharp has a nice RubberStamp implementation, but it does not let you specify custom images, only the predefined icons like TopSecret.

I have tried to analyze other PDF files with custom Stamps and tried to **mimic** the same structure as they have, by manually creating the **XObjects**, adding the image to the **Resources**, and creating an **Appearance Stream**.

Long story short, it's not working. I have a feeling that simply writing the object to the Appearance-Stream is not a good idea, even though the image gets to the file, I can see the annotation rectangle in the PDF Viewer, but it's a blank white rect, showing nothing.

Ideally, I would like to trigger PDFSharp to create the Appearance Stream, but after several hours of online research, I haven't found anything useful.

Can anyone point me out how can I add a custom image to the RubberStamp Appearance-Stream? Or trigger the PdfSharp to recreate the Appearance-Stream?

```
public void SavePdf()
{
    System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

    // Create a new PDF document
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
    pdfDocument.Version = 15;

    // Create an empty page
    PdfPage pdfPage;
    pdfPage = pdfDocument.AddPage();
    pdfPage.Width = XUnit.FromInch(8.5);
    pdfPage.Height = XUnit.FromInch(11.00);

    // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage);

    // Creating the Rubber Stamp with some default settings
    PdfRubberStampAnnotation cstamp = new PdfRubberStampAnnotation() { Icon = PdfRubberStampAnnotationIcon.TopSecret };
    XRect rect = gfx.Transformer.WorldToDefaultPage(new XRect(new XPoint(10, 10), new XSize(200, 50)));
    cstamp.Rectangle = new PdfRectangle(rect);
    cstamp.Color = XColor.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);

    // Load the custom image
    var image = XImage.FromFile(@"c:\temp\test.bmp");
    var pdfImage = new PdfImage(pdfDocument, image);
    string r = pdfPage.Resources.AddImage(pdfImage); // adding the image to the Page References

    // Now let's create the XForm object, and reference the image
    var matrix = new PdfArray();
    matrix.Elements.Add(new PdfReal(1));
    matrix.Elements.Add(new PdfReal(0));
    matrix.Elements.Add(new PdfReal(0));
    matrix.Elements.Add(new PdfReal(1));
    matrix.Elements.Add(new PdfReal(0));
    matrix.Elements.Add(new PdfReal(0));

    var xform = new PdfDictionary(pdfDocument);
    xform.Elements.Add("/Type", new PdfName("/XObject"));
    xform.Elements.Add("/Subtype", new PdfName("/Form"));
    xform.Elements.Add("/FormType", new PdfInteger(1));
    xform.Elements.Add("/BBox", new PdfRectangle(new XRect(10, 10, image.PointWidth, image.PointHeight)));
    xform.Elements.Add("/Matrix", matrix);
    xform.Elements.Add("/Resources", pdfImage.Reference);
    xform.Elements.Add("/Length", new PdfInteger(0));

    // Now let's create the appearance stream, and add the XForm object
    var appearanceStream = new PdfDictionary(pdfDocument);
    appearanceStream.Elements.Add("/N", xform);
    cstamp.Elements.Add("/AP", appearanceStream);

    // Add to the page
    gfx.PdfPage.Annotations.Add(cstamp);

    pdfDocument.Save(@"c:\temp\1.pdf");
}
```

**Edit 1**: I have tried to add the Form as a Stream with the library, but I don't see an obvious way to do it. CreateStream seems to be an empty stream, and the **xform** variable has no reference at this point, so I can't attach the Reference to the /N. Maybe it's not even possible with this library?

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
appearanceStream.Stream = xform.CreateStream(buffer);
appearanceStream.Elements["/N"] = new PdfString(string.Format("q\n200 0 0 200 0 0 cm\n{0} Do\n Q", r));
```

Answer (score 0):

The xform needs to be a stream and you have to actually draw the image in this stream:

```
q
10 0 0 10 0 0 cm
/ImageID Do
Q
```

10 is the size of your xform (from your code) so the code above scales the image to cover the whole xform.
The `/ImageID` is the image identifier in the xform resources (I assume the r variable contains this value).

Please see the screenshot below that shows the COS objects structure in the PDF file for the custom stamp annotation. `XO0` is the id of the image used as custom appearance.
[image]